# Bash Completion script to complete file path after certain arguments options

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete

I am writing a bash completion script for a command-line tool:

```
_plink()
{
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    opts="--1 --23file --a1-allele --a2-allele --adjust --aec"

    if [[ ${cur} == --*file ]] || [[ ${cur} == --out ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$(ls)" -- ${cur}) )
    elif [[ ${cur} == -* ]] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    fi
}
complete -F _plink plink1.9
```

The idea is if the after the option `--*file` and `--out`, bash should autocomplete the file path.
Right now I am using "`$(ls)`" which only completes the filenames in current working path. Any suggestions?

Comment: `compgen -o filenames -G "$cur*"`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `compgen -f` to complete filenames, like this:

```
if [[ ${prev} == --*file ]] || [[ ${prev} == --out ]]; then
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -f -- ${cur}) )
elif ...
```

However, `compgen -f` isn't great at completing filenames because it doesn't honour spaces in filenames.

A better way is to use the `_filedir` function available in [bash-completion-lib](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/bash-completion). It might already be available on your system (type: `declare -f _filedir` to check).

Using `_filedir`, your completion function becomes:

```
if [[ ${prev} == --*file ]] || [[ ${prev} == --out ]]; then
    _filedir
elif ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively if you do not have the [bash-completion-lib](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/bash-completion), I looked at the [source](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/bash-completion/blob/master/bash_completion) of the _filedir() function and was able to get full bash completion using `comptopt -o` along with `compgen -f`:

```
if [[ ${prev} == --*file ]] || [[ ${prev} == --out ]]; then
    comptopt -o filenames 2>/dev/null
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -f -- ${cur}) )
elif ...
```

However, you do not get the functionality of resolving ~usernames or case-insensitivity that _filedir() provides.

Comment: A minor typo: `s/comptopt/compopt/`