# How to use bash_autocomplete for the second argument?

Tags: bash

Use case: I am trying to get `source activate <env>` to autocomplete the names of my conda environments (i.e. the list of directories in `~/anaconda3/envs/`).

I've managed to get it to work if I didn't need the 'activate' in there using this code:

```
_source ()
{
    local cur

    COMPREPLY=()
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}

    COMPREPLY=($(ls ~/anaconda3/envs | xargs -I dirs bash -c "compgen -W dirs $cur"))

    return 0
}

complete -F _source source
```

I've tried setting the last argument of `complete` to `source\ activate` and `'source activate'` but that's not working (it just autocompletes with local files).

The issue seems to be that because `source activate` is not a function, it doesn't pick it up.

The simple solution is, of course, to make a single-word bash script which just contains `source activate $1`. But I'd rather do it properly!

Comment: Defining a wrapper function, the supplying a completion for that, *is* the proper way. You don't want every call to `source` to complete its second argument based on the contents of `~/anaconda/envs`.

Comment: I've never come across a case where I've wanted `source activate` to take anything else - I've only seen `source` used on its own. Do you have any examples?

Comment: `source` is a built-in shell command for executing an arbitrary shell script in the current shell rather than in a separate process. `source activate` is not a single command; it's just a call to `source` with `activate` as its first argument (the name of the script).

Comment: Got it, thanks.

The issue I'm having now (with a wrapper function which is just `source activate $1`) is that the `source` doesn't seem to execute in the global scope - I get the expected messages telling me things are being taken off and added to my path, so it's working somewhere, but it doesn't change anything in the scope from which I called my wrapper script.

Comment: Ha... so the way to get it to execute in the global scope is, of course, `source`. Which makes my wrapper function the first argument, which means I can't use the autocompletion. Any way around this?

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing. My suggestion is to define `activate_conda () { source activate "$1"; }`, then define a completion function for `activate_conda`.

Comment: That's what I've done (I think) - `/usr/bin/local/pysource` just contains a shebang and `source activate $1`, and then my completion function is basically what I put in my first post but with `complete -F _pysource pysource` as the last line. 

However, because `pysource` executes in its own subshell, `activate` only changes the `PATH` in that subshell. The way to get it to change the global `PATH` is using `source pysource <env>`, which leaves me exactly where I started.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was adapted from [this conda issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2595).

It checks that the first argument is `activate` and then does the compgen using whatever the second word you're typing is.

```
#!/bin/bash
_complete_source_activate_conda(){
      if [ ${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]} != "activate" ]
      then
          return 0
      fi
      local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
      COMPREPLY=($(ls ~/anaconda3/envs | xargs -I dirs bash -c "compgen -W dirs $cur"))
      return 0
}

complete -F _complete_source_activate_conda source
```

Put that script in /etc/bash_completion.d/. Unfortunately it kills the first-word autocompletion - with some more fiddling it would probably be able to handle both.

Comment: Getting the first-word autocompletion back would be a case of altering the if statement, and using [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23999768/2700168).

Answer (score 0):

getting autocomplete to work for the second argument can be done with a case statement
like this

```
_source()
{
    local cur prev opts
    case $COMP_CWORD in
        1) opts="activate";;
        2)  [ ${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]} = "activate" ] && opts=$(ls ~/anaconda3/envs | xargs -I dirs bash -c "compgen -W dirs $cur");;
        *);;
    esac
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$opts" -- ${cur}) )
    return 0
}
complete -F _source source
```

compgen is  build in function of bash which you then give the options you want to complete for with `$opts` for the first argument it will authocomplete "activate" but that can be adapted to be a more existive list and for the second argument it first checks if the first argument is "activate" before attempting to complete

disclaimer i adapted this from a completion function i wrote for [ubports-qa](https://github.com/ubports/ubports-qa-scripts/pull/25), i haven't been able to test it but it should just work